# Exporting environment variables both to bash as csh using a bash script with functions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csh

I have a bash shell-script with a function which exports an environment variable.
For sake of argument lets use the following example:

```
#!/bin/bash

function my_function()
{
    export my_env_var=$1
}
```

Since the whole purpose is to export the variable to the main shell I `source` it.

When the main shell is bash this works fine:

```
<bash-shell>
> source ~/tmp/my_test.sh
> my_function test
> echo $my_env_var
test
```

But other customers use csh and there things start to fail if I use the same command with the same script, since csh does not know functions :-(

```
<csh-shell>
% source ~/tmp/my_test.sh
Badly placed ()'s
```

I already tried to wrap it in a wrapper-script:

```
#!/bin/sh
bash -c 'source ~/tmp/my_test.sh; my_function test`
echo my_env_var = $my_env_var
```

But my_env_var is not exported in this way:

```
<csh-shell>
% source ~/tmp/my_test2.sh 
my_env_var: Undefined variable.
```

Where it is known in the bash shell (as can be seen by changing the 2nd script to:

```
#!/bin/sh
bash -c 'source ~/tmp/my_test.sh; my_function test; echo my_env_var in bash = $my_env_var`
echo my_env_var = $my_env_var
```

```
<csh-shell>
% source ~/tmp/my_test2.sh 
my_env_var in bash = test
my_env_var: Undefined variable.
```

What am I missing / doing wrong so the script exports the variable when it is called from bash and when it is called from csh?

Comment: You'll have to write a csh version of your bash script. csh users are probably used to look for the equivalent `.csh` of the files to source.

Comment: @fravadona: First thank you for your answer.
I already thought about that, but the function is way less simple than I gave in the example above. The essential part is that in the end it determines a value and stores that in an environment variable which the user has to use from his/her shell

Comment: Why don't you post your bash function? you might be able to convert it to a csh alias

Comment: @Fravadona: My company does not allow that since they are afraid that company secrets are shown in that way. So I always have to use pseudo code to describe the core of the problem :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bourne shell and csh are not compatible; many commands are different, and csh misses many features (it doesn't have functions at all). Plus, sooner or later you're going to have someone who uses fish, which is different yet still. The only way to make a non-trivial script work for both is to write it twice.

That said, if you want to set some environment variables then the general strategy is to create a script which outputs the required commands; this can be in *any* language (shell, Python, C); for example:

```
#!/bin/sh

# ... do work here ...
var="foo"

# Getting the shell in a cross-platform way isn't too easy. This was only tested
# on Linux. Can add a "-c" or "-f" flag if you need cross-platform support.
shell=$(ps -ho comm $(ps -ho ppid $$))

case "$shell" in
    (csh|tcsh)  echo "setenv VAR $var" ;;
    (fish)      echo "set -Ux VAR $var" ;;
    (*)         echo "export VAR=$var"
esac
```

And when you run it, it outputs the appropriate commands:

```
% ./work
export VAR=foo

% tcsh
> ./work
setenv VAR foo

> fish
martin@x270 ~> ./work
set -Ux VAR foo
```

And to actually set it, eval the output like so:

```
% eval $(./work)
% echo $VAR
foo

% tcsh
> eval `./work`
> echo $VAR
foo

> fish
martin@x270 ~> eval (./work)
martin@x270 ~> echo $VAR
foo
```

---

The downside of this is that informational messages, warnings, etc. will also get eval'd; to solve this make sure to always output these to stderr:

```
echo >&2 "warning: foo"
```

---

If you don't want to run `eval` you can also use something slightly more complicated which prints `VAR=foo` and then create a Bourne and csh wrapper script to parse those lines, but "output the variables you want to set, instead of directly setting them" is the general approach to take to make something work in multiple incompatible shells.

Comment: This solution looks nice. Thank you
But....Is there a way to combine the case-esac and the eval into 1 script? (Probably not, but I have to ask to be certain ;-)).
I want to avoid users being confused in which script they have to call, so I try to create 1 script to rule them all which in the end does the work.

Comment: @Nemelis You have only one script with this approach (named `work` in this example): the only thing that's needed for your users is to use the correct command in the shell startup file. Actually, `eval \`./work\`` will work in both Bourne and tcsh (the `$( .. )` syntax is just a bit nicer), so I don't foresee any huge problems with confused users.

Comment: If I follow your recipe for just one variable I got it working.

But what if you have to export multiple variables (for example a "http_proxy" variable and a "https_proxy" variable.
Now - for example - eval on tcsh prints out "setenv: too many arguments" (basically since it are 2 setenv commands and apparently eval makes 1 line out of the echo, where it needs to be 2)

Comment: I made the code so that I call the the inner script (which checks which shell is called and according to that creates the echo command) 2x from the outer script  (which does the eval). That made the inner script easier, although the outer script now has to provide the name of the environment variable